# Customizing properties dialog screen in IBM Content Navigator

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

I need to develop a functionality in IBM Content Navigator where after search for an item, right click it-> Properties, I need to either:

1 - add a button in properties dialog screen that will call a service and open another dialog;
2 - or extend the Save button functionality to also call a service and open another dialog;

What's quickest way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look @ ecm.widget.dialog.EditPropertiesDialog and onSave() method. This might help you to extend save button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your customized code by using aspect before/after:

(choose either depending on your functionality)

```
aspect.after(ecm.widget.dialog.EditPropertiesDialog.prototype,"onSave", function(event){
    ......
});
```

```
aspect.before(ecm.widget.dialog.EditPropertiesDialog.prototype,"onSave", function(event){
    ......
});
```